# How to set default file permissions for all folders/files in a directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

I want to set a folder such that anything created within it (directories, files) inherit default permissions and group.

Lets call the group "media".  And also, the folders/files created within the directory should have g+rw automatically.

Comment: Isn't that controlled by the user creating the new file/folder, and his umask?

Comment: umask does relate to permissions but I do not believe it does anything with setting a default group that is not the user him/herself.

Comment: What OS? Tags needed. `setfacl` and default ACLs don't exist on AIX.

Answer (score 395, accepted):

I found it: [Applying default permissions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/applying-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-within-a-specific-folder-605129/)

From the article:

1. Set the `setgid` bit, so that files/folder under <directory> will be created with the same group as <directory>

   ```bsh
   chmod g+s <directory>
   ```
2. Set the default ACLs for the group and other

   ```bsh
   setfacl -d -m g::rwx /<directory>
   setfacl -d -m o::rx /<directory>
   ```

Next we can verify:

```
getfacl /<directory>
```

Output:

```
# file: ../<directory>/
# owner: <user>
# group: media
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Comment: Yay for the sticky bit!

Comment: Lets not confuse gid with sticky bit.

Comment: Why is the chmod g+s needed? Running a test in /tmp I seem to only need setfacl -d -m o::rx

Comment: g+s will ensure that new content in the directory will inherit the group ownership. setfacl only changes the chmod, in your case sets the permission to o=rx

Comment: Note that ACL must be enabled (included as one of the mount options for the mounted file system) for the file permissions to be inherited.

Comment: @gabe `s` stands for `set-user-ID` or `set-group-ID`, `t` is the sticky bit.

Comment: An alternative way to achieve a similar result without setting sticky bit would be `setfacl -d -m g:<directory group>:rwx <directory>`. That way files created under <directory> will be `rw` by members of <directory>'s group.

Comment: What do I do if I receive the following error: `command not found: setfacl`

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy: does `sudo apt-get install acl` resolves the problem?

Comment: [Make all new files in a directory accessible to a group](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/make-all-new-files-in-a-directory-accessible-to-a-group) has a more detailed answer about setting up ACLs for this case.

Comment: I found [here](http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2010/03/shared-folders-in-ubuntu-with-setgid.html) nice tutorial about ACL

Comment: You might want to consider using 'X' instead so it will only set execute permission on directories not files `setfacl -d -m g::rwX /<directory>`

Comment: If your on Debian to run “setfacl” you need to make sure that “acl” (https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions) is intalled. To install use “apt-get install acl”. Use “sudo apt-get install acl” if needed.

Comment: Nice one! Just want to add if you want to completely remove perms for others like 640, should do: `setfacl -d -m o::- /<dir>`

Comment: Where do the leading slashes in `/<directory>` come from?

Comment: where is the documentation that says capital X is for directories only?

Comment: @Arrow_Raider under "man setfacl", in ACL ENTRIES section, last paragraph.

Comment: this is not supposed to work for new files created in previously created directory inside the main directory, right? It's not working for me. It works for new files created right inside the main directory. How to apply this thing recursively?

Comment: `setfacl` is do longer installed in ubuntu 20.02 by default - install it using `apt install acl`

Answer (score 48):

This is an addition to Chris' answer, it's based on my experience on my Arch Linux rig.

Using the default switch (`-d`) and the modify switch (`-m`) will only modify the default permissions but leave the existing ones intact:

```bash
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /<directory>
```

If you want to change folder's entire permission structure including the existing ones (you'll have to do an extra line and make it recursive with `-R`):

```bash
setfacl -R -m g::rwx /<directory>
```

**Examples**:

```bash
# Gives group read,write,exec permissions for currently existing files and
# folders, recursively.
setfacl -R -m g::rwx /home/limited.users/directory 

# Revokes read and write permission for everyone else in existing folder and
# subfolders.
setfacl -R -m o::x /home/limited.users/directory  

# Gives group rwx permissions by default, recursively.
setfacl -R -d -m g::rwx /home/limited.users/directory

# Revokes read, write and execute permissions for everyone else. 
setfacl -R -d -m o::--- /home/limited.users/directory
```

(**CREDIT** to markdwite in comments for the syntax of the revoke all privileges line)

Comment: To revoke group privileges (as an example): sudo setfacl -d -m g::--- /path

Comment: is that just a typo specifying `setfacl -R -m g::rwx /<directory>` twice in your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Add yourself/logged user to www-data group, so we can work with files created by www-data server

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER
```

Needs to restart/relogin so the newly added group takes effect

```
cd /var/www
```

Add www-data as group member of html folder, and your user as owner, so we own it as well as a group member

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data html
```

Put your username in place of USER

Set read,write,execute permission as required, (ugo) u=user, g=group, o=others

```
sudo chmod 750 html
```

Set the GID of html, now, newly created files in html will inherit ownership permissions:

```
sudo chmod g+s html
```

This creates the default rules for newly created files/dirs within the html directory and sub directories.

```
sudo setfacl -R -d -m u::rwX -m g::rX -m o::000 html
```

Make SELinux if installed, ignore www-data context requirement so it lets allows write permissions

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

list directory to see new permissions applied

```
ls -ld html
```

Returns this

```
drwxrwsr-x+   3 html www-data
```

The trailing + signify that ACL, Access Control List, is set on the directory.

***Reference***: [Link to forum](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/applying-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-within-a-specific-folder-605129/#post2982934)

Answer (score 0):

Above answer doesn't updates executable permissions, though they show so. Use
`chacl -r u::rwx,g::r-x,o::r-- ./`

Answer (score -3):

Using the following command you can set default permission to a file:

```
chacl -R filename
```

Comment: How this differ from other answers? And give some examples

Comment: Are you sure that's what it does? https://linux.die.net/man/1/chacl indicates that it will *remove* an ACL.