# Make all new files in a directory accessible to a group

Tags: permissions, group, acl, umask

Suppose I have two users Alice and Bob and a group GROUPNAME and a folder `foo`, both users are members of GROUPNAME (using Linux and ext3).

If I save as user Alice a file under `foo`, the permissions are: `-rw-r--r-- Alice Alice`. However, is it possible to achieve that every file saved under some subdirectory of `foo` has permissions `-rwxrwx--- Alice GROUPNAME` (i.e. owner Alice, group GROUPNAME)?

Comment: Related: [How are ACL permissions processed and in what order do they apply to a given user action?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92408/135943)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can control the assigned permission bits with `umask`, and the group by making the directory *setgid* to `GROUPNAME`.

```
$ umask 002            # allow group write; everyone must do this
$ chgrp GROUPNAME .    # set directory group to GROUPNAME
$ chmod g+s .          # files created in directory will be in group GROUPNAME
```

Note that you have to do the `chgrp`/`chmod` for every subdirectory; it doesn't propagate automatically for existing directories.  On OS X, subsequently created directories under a *setgid* directory will be *setgid*, although the latter will be in group `GROUPNAME`.  On most Linux distros, the *setgid* bit will propagate to new subdirectories.

Also note that `umask` is a process attribute and applies to all files created by that process and its children (which inherit the `umask` in effect in their parent at `fork()` time).  Users may need to set this in `~/.profile`, and may need to watch out for things unrelated to your directory that need different permissions.  [modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net) may be useful if you need different settings when doing different things.

You can control things a bit better if you can use POSIX ACLs; it should be possible to specify both a permissions mask and a group, and have them propagate sensibly.  Support for POSIX ACLs is somewhat variable, though.

Comment: Subdirectories created after setting setgid on the parent directory will have setgid set automatically.

Comment: @Arrowmaster: On some systems, perhaps, but not all; I tested on OSX and it doesn't propagate, at least for non-root.

Comment: Well on Debian (and I assume most other Linux distros) the setgid and group name both propagate.

Comment: On OS X, the setgid bit on a directory is just ignored; new files and directories are *always* given the group of their containing directory.

Comment: Is it also possible that files copied or moved to foo (using cp resp. mv) gain the desired permissions automatically (`-rwxrwx--- A G`)?

Comment: If your OS doesn't support ACLs, or your file system can't be configured to use ACLs, then this is a good answer. However if you can use ACLs, that is a better approach. See the answer from @Gilles below.

Comment: `Note that you have to do the chgrp/chmod for every subdirectory; it doesn't propagate automatically` — is there a reason why the `-R` flag can't fix this?  Or is that flag non-portable?

Comment: I have made it, and test, it works! But this doesn't help a lot in my case as new folders are creating with drwxrwxr-x BUT files with -rw-r--r-- and it is not writeable for users in the same group.

Comment: @fdrv Remember to run `umask 002` for each new shell, or put it into `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` to make it permanent.

Answer (score 148):

If at all possible, use [access control lists (ACL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

Under Linux, make sure that the filesystem you're using supports ACLs (most unix filesystems do). You may need to change the mount options to enable ACLs: with ext2/ext3/ext4, [the kernel default since 2.6.39 is to enable ACLs](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ea6633369458992241599c9d9ebadffaeddec164). On older kernels you may to need to specify the `acl` mount option explicitly, so the entry in `/etc/fstab` should look like `/dev/sda1  /  ext4  errors=remount-ro,acl  0 1`. Run `mount -o remount,acl /` to activate ACLs without rebooting. Also install the ACL command line tools `getfacl` and `setfacl`, typically provided in a package called `acl`.

Now that the one-time setup is over, change the directory's ACL to give the group write permissions and to make these permissions inherited by newly created files. Under Linux:

```
setfacl -d -m group:GROUPNAME:rwx /path/to/directory
setfacl -m group:GROUPNAME:rwx /path/to/directory
```

---

If ACLs are not an option, make the directory owned by the group `GROUPNAME`, and set its permissions to 2775 or 2770: `chmod g+rwxs /path/to/directory`. The `s` here means the setgid bit; for a directory, it means that files created in this directory will belong to the group that owns the directory.

You'll also need to set Alice and Bob's [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) to make all their files group-writable by default. The default umask on most systems is 022, meaning that files can have all permissions except write by group and other. Change that to 002, meaning to forbid only write-by-other permission. You would typically put that setting in your `~/.profile`:

```
umask 002    # or 007 to have files not readable by others
```

Comment: +1 - Very thorough answer. I never knew one could remount / on-the-fly. Good to know.

Comment: Thie setfacl -d command does not work for me because the files contained within that directory have an r-- mask that negates any write permissions. Would love some help. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71743/using-setfacl-to-allow-group-members-to-write-to-any-file-in-a-directory

Comment: Nice answer, but after following all these steps, it seems that when I untar a file, it inherits the permissions of the file as it was inside the .tar file. So I end up with something that works for normal usage, but as soon as someone extracts a .tar file, no one else can edit anything inside it. Do you know if there is anything I can do about that?

Comment: **Q1.** Are you sure you should add `acl` as an option in `mount` command when you have it added in `/etc/fstab`? I think it's redundant and especially because when you run the `mount` command in your answer (i.e. `mount -o remount,acl /`), you'll get an output like this: `/dev/vda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,acl,acl)` (see `acl,acl` in the end). Is that okay? Please correct it if I am not wrong.

Comment: **Q2.** You said, *"Now that the one-time setup is over, change the directory's ACL to give the group write permissions and to make these permissions inherited by newly created files."* But you've got the order of the commands wrong, haven't you? i.e. the one with the `-d` option should come next as it's the command that sets permissions for the newly created files. Right?

Comment: @its_me Q1: I show a `mount` command with the `remount` option, so it doesn't use `fstab`. Having `acl` twice means that the filesystem was mounted with the `acl` option already, and it harmless. `acl` [is the default](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79970/mount-options-shown-in-proc-mounts) for ext4 in recent kernels, by the way (the patch was still brand new back when I wrote this answer). Q2: You can run the commands in either order.

Comment: **Q2:** I understand that the commands can be run in either order. But was I correct about the ordering w.r.t what they do? (Thanks for the clarification.)

Comment: @Mike I think I see what's happening: the ACL is present, but the mask is set to e.g. `r--` for a 644 file which kills a `w` bit in a group entry. Hmmm. I would have thought that adding a `default:mask rwx` entry on the directory would solve this (see Ben's question), but it doesn't, I don't understand why.

Comment: @its_me Yes, your understanding is correct, it's just that it doesn't matter in what order you add the entries

Comment: @Gilles wrt acl being the default for ext4 in recent kernels, that's true for the standard system-installed mount points but not for partitions added manually post-install.  Those still need an explicit "acl" option in fstab.  wrt the `default:mask:rwx` not overriding an existing `mask:r--`, the default mask only applies to the creation of new files and directories.  One of two things can be done: set the mask (not default mask) with `setfacl -m m:rwx [file]` or touch a group permission: `chmod g+rwx` or `setfacl -m g::rwx`.  That will force a recalculation of the mask to not interfere.

Comment: Also, `setfacl -d -m group:G:rwx /path/to/directory
setfacl -m group:G:rwx /path/to/directory` can be shortened to: `setfacl -m d:g:G:rwx,g:G:rwx /path/to directory`.  I usually default the mask as well a la: `setfacl -m d:g:G:rwx,g:G:rwx,d:m:rwx`.

Comment: all these commands give me this error: `setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 1`, using ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: @knocte You must have made a mistake when copying them. I've just checked, and no, there is no strange bug that makes them fail on Ubuntu 16.04. You need to replace `G` by a valid group name, but if you forget to do that, you get an error message referring to character 7, not character 1.

Comment: you should improve the answer then to use `GROUPNAME` instead of `G`, to make it more clear

Comment: @mopsled Please don't edit an answer is a way that doesn't match the question. `GROUPNAME` may be clearer than `G`, but if you make that edit, you need to edit the question and the other answers to match.

Comment: @Gilles My mistake, thank you for cleaning up the question and other answers.

Comment: Group inheriting will only work for newly created or copied files in a setgid dir, but not for files or dirs *moved* into the setgid dir. Why is that? This is making me crazy.

Comment: @red-o-alf `mv` preserves all the attributes of the moved file, because it moves the file with all of its metadata. It's a limitation of the Unix group approach to permissions: it only has settings on each file, it doesn't have an “inherit” setting that would be preserved when moving. The semantics of `mv foo bar/` with respect to permissions is “keep the original access permissions of `foo`”, not “adapt `foo` to a new permissions context”.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thanks, now I understand the reason why natively it works that way. But after decades of Unix systems I still can't see how some additional standard software interface was not built to allow for moved files , unzipped files, downloaded files, and so on, to work in a consistent way with regards to the acquisition of permissions., should a sys admin decide so. It would slow down the system operation? OK! Deal! It's all about pros and cons... We've been dealing for ages with incredibly slow DB solutions, and not setgid? -WAIT!- a DB is probably what I'm looking for !?!

Answer (score 28):

This question is a good fit for linux [`acl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). Since you don't state your OS, I'll assume Linux in what follows. Here is an example session.

I don't know of a really good `acl` tutorial, but you could do worse than ["Using ACLs with Fedora Core 2 (Linux Kernel 2.6.5)" by Van Emery](https://web.archive.org/web/20191227121823/http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/linux-acl.html).

Note that the default `acl` behaves like a local umask. Since at least in Linux, umasks are applied globally, this is the only way I know to get the effect of a local umask. For some reason this a little known feature. The net is littered with people asking about a local umask override, but almost nobody seems to think of using `acl`.

Also note that you need to mount the partition you are working in with `acl` support, eg.

```
/dev/mapper/debian-acl /mnt/acl        ext3    defaults,acl        0       2
```

Session follows:

```
/mnt/acl$ mkdir foo
/mnt/acl$ getfacl foo
# file: foo
# owner: faheem
# group: faheem
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Set the group of `foo` to be `staff`, and set the acl of group and user of `foo` to `rwx`.

```
/mnt/acl$ chgrp staff foo
/mnt/acl$ setfacl -R -m u::rwx,g::rwx foo
/mnt/acl$ getfacl foo
# file: foo
# owner: faheem
# group: staff
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

Set default acls of user and group to `rwx` as well. This defines permissions that files and directories inherit from `foo`. So all files and directories created under foo will have group permissions `rw`.

```
/mnt/acl$ setfacl -d --set u::rwx,g::rwx,o::- foo
/mnt/acl$ getfacl foo
# file: foo
# owner: faheem
# group: staff
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::---
```

Now create some files in `foo` as users `faheem` and `john`.

```
/mnt/acl$ cd foo
/mnt/acl/foo$ touch bar

# switch to user john for this next command.

/mnt/acl/foo$ touch baz
```

List files. Notice that both files owned by `faheem` and files owned by `john` are created with group permissions `rw`.

```
/mnt/acl/foo$ ls -la
total 3
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 faheem staff  1024 May  9 01:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 faheem faheem 1024 May  9 01:20 ..
-rw-rw----  1 faheem faheem    0 May  9 01:20 bar
-rw-rw----  1 john   john      0 May  9 01:22 baz
```