# Configure permissions

Tags: ssh, permissions, git

I'm sharing a git repository with a friend over SSH. He pushes from and pulls to his git repository using my machine's SSH server, where the shared git repository is.

Problem is that when he pushes a commit, I can't pull, because the commit is `janito users rwx------` (these are permission metadata).

I created a group called git, added him and myself, and the repository is `jpmelos git rwxrwx---`. How can I force files created in the repository directory to be `<creator> git rwxrwx---` as well, so we can always pull and push without worrying about permissions?

Or you can suggest better solutions to the problem, of course. Restrictions are that we need to use the SSH on my machine (we are not ready to make the code public yet) and we are already pushing and pulling from a bare repository I created separately from my working repository.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission of saved files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/permission-of-saved-files)

Answer (score 3):

The umask issues can be taken care with the `core.sharedRepository` Git configuration variable:

```
( cd /path/to/shared-repository.git &&
git config --bool core.sharedRepository true
)
```

Whenever Git creates a new file or directory, it will make sure the group bits are set appropriately (always group readable, group writable and executable when appropriate—even if the invoking user’s umask is overly “wide”).
Note: The `core.sharedRepository` setting only applies to entries Git itself makes, so it will not help set the permissions of entries in the working tree of a non-bare repository. You will have to set your umask manually for that.

You can make new files and directories be group-owned by your `git` group by setting the [setgid bit on the directories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories) (after `chgrp`ing the file and directories to the appropriate group).

```
chgrp -R git /path/to/shared-repository.git &&
find /path/to/shared-repository.git -type d -exec chmod g=rwxs '{}' \;
```

---

If you are creating a new repository from scratch, you can just `chgrp` an empty directory and run `git init --shared` on it (Git will set `core.sharedRepository` and do the `chmod g=rwxs` on the GIT_DIR):

```
mkdir new-shared.git &&
chgrp git new-shared.git &&
git init --bare --shared new-shared.git
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your friend's umask setting?  Have him type `umask` at his command prompt on your server and see what comes up.  If it reads `0077` (or `077`), that's likely the problem, because that means "when creating files, clear all permission bits for group or other".

A more appropriate umask would be `0027`, which will allow group read and execute permissions on created files.  He can set this temporarily by running `umask 0027`, or permanently by adding it to his `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: This won't quite solve the problem... It will create `janito users rwxr-x---` files, but I want only users in the group `git` to have access to those files. So, I need `janito git rwxrwx---`.

Comment: Ah, yes!  You can't use the filesystem to force permissions, but you can force group ownership.  Run `chmod g+s` on your .git directory and all of its subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be done by writing a custom script as a Git hook—any scripting language will do as long as everyone cloning the Git repo can use it. [Read about Git hooks at Pro Git.](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check out [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way).

Under this system a special git account is created to host all your repositories.  As the gitosis admin you just add your users' ssh public keys in order grant access.  Your git urls end up looking like this:

ssh://git@myserver/my-repo.git

All users connect using the git user account but it's secure because shell access isn't allowed.  Instead all access is forced to go through gitosis which can regulate and secure access to individual git repositories in a configurable way.  And your permission problem doesn't come up because only the single git user ever actually interacts with the file system.

Comment: Gitosis is no longer actively developed (or maintained). You might want to consider recommending [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Other things to consider:

pam_umask

To use pam to control umask, have `UsePAM yes` in sshd_config, and this in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session    optional     pam_umask.so umask=0027
```

acls

Read [Gilles' post here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/permission-of-saved-files/12847#12847).  It includes install instructions.  I don't know if it's a dupe question but that page is worth a read :-)

To fix acls in your already existing repository:

```
find git_repository/ -type d -exec setfacl -m d:g:git:rwx {}
find git_repository/ -f -exec setfacl -m g:git:rwx {}
```

quick and dirty: hook

Create a hook as previously mentioned, edit `git_repository/hooks/post-update` to be:

```
#!/bin/sh
chmod -R g+w . 2>/dev/null
chgrp -R git . 2>/dev/null
```

That'll fix things after each update and will probably do fine for a small repository and 2 users.  Probably not for larger, busy repositories ;-)