# File and Folder permissions

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown, file-sharing

I have copied some data from a client's home folder to a group work folder accessed by a group in Linux. Other clients can see most of the data except some in a specific folder.

When the new client tries to access the data from a Windows machine, the directories are shown as empty. 
When the same folder is accessed through Linux using ssh, the client gets a "permission denied" error.

This looks like a permissions issue for the new client, the folder permissions are;
drwxrwsr-x  2 root  4096 Feb 1 11:14

and file permissions are
-rw-rw---- 1 root   11 Feb  1 21:18 
-rwxrw-r-- 1 root   1500 Feb  1 21:18

The user trying to access these files and folders is already in the group which has permissions to this work area.
Should I do a
**chmod -R 774 /folder_path** and then
**chown -R (saket):(scannergrp) /folder_path**

Comment: Could you please say what is the groupname?

Comment: It may be worth running 'namei -l <target dir>' to see if the permissions on the parent directories are not what you require.

Comment: sounds like posting relevant sections of smb.conf could be good too

Comment: Brett, you are on the ball and yes ivanian, further information was needed; because the folders were copied to an existing directory there were some folders where the permissions did not apply correctly and had the permissions  <br/>drwxrwS---  also read the following <br/>http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118853/what-does-the-s-attribute-in-file-permissions-mean and http://superuser.com/questions/509114/what-does-directory-permission-s-mean-not-lower-case-but-in-upper-case   sudo find /correct/folder/path -type d -exec chmod g+x "{}" \;  fixed it for the user. Thank you all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Brett, you are on the correct path, and yes, ivanian, further information was needed; since the folders were copied to an existing directory there were some folders where the permissions did not apply correctly and had the permissions
`drwxrwS---`.

Also read [What does the 's' attribute in file permissions mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118853/what-does-the-s-attribute-in-file-permissions-mean)

The command below applied the correct permissions.

```
sudo find /correct/folder/path -type d -exec chmod g+x "{}" \;
```