# What is set-group-ID on execution - ignored and why am I unable to unzip a file because of it?

Tags: permissions, zip

I'm trying to unzip a file using `gunzip GCF_000746645.1_ASM74664v1_genomic.fna.gz` but I get the following error:

```
gzip: GCF_000746645.1_ASM74664v1_genomic.fna.gz is set-group-ID on execution - ignored
```

I've learned that set-group-ID on execution refers to something related to permissions on the server, but I'm not entirely sure how so and what I should do. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Read `man -a chmod`. What permissions are set on the `*.fna.gz` file?

Comment: Ah I just tried it out and see that I don't have write permissions in this directory. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Just decompress it to stdout: `gzip -cd GCF_000746645.1_ASM74664v1_genomic.fna.gz > GCF_000746645.1_ASM74664v1_genomic.fna`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security mechanism for files with setuid, setgid or sticky bit set. Gzip refuses to compress or decompress
files with those permissions and exits with exit status 2 and a warning message.

It doesn't matter if the executable bit is also set in combination with setuid, setgid (`s` if executable, `S` if non-executable) or the sticky bit
(`t` if executable, `T` if non-executable).

Check the permissions with `ls -l` or `stat`.

To remove the setgid bit, run

```
chmod g-s GCF_000746645.1_ASM74664v1_genomic.fna.gz
```

Related:

- [Understanding UNIX permissions and file types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types)
- [What's the difference between “s” and “S” in ls -la?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28363/whats-the-difference-between-s-and-s-in-ls-la/28365)