# Using umask to set group permissions

Tags: permissions, group, umask

A long time ago an old friend showed me a way to use an octal or hex umask with a group I think using `/etc/profile`. I'm not sure.

I'm trying to create group on Debian so that every member of that group when creating a file will produce a file with default permissions `665`. And when creating a directory it will have default permissions `775`. What are some ways to do this for a group setting?

Thanks

Comment: thanks hesse for those edits...i will remember for future edits

Comment: So basically, you want to automatically set a umask of `002` for all members of a certain group?  I might go dig around in PAM, e.g. adding a `pam_umask` invocation to `common-session` or something similar.

Comment: @jw013 wow, I think that's close to exactly what he did. in /etc/profile the last line created a umask of 002.

Comment: In case you aren't aware of it, you can do default umask overrides on a per directory basis with `acl`. See eg http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/permission-of-saved-files

Answer (score 1):

Not really `umask` aka [(user mask)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) is set by user.  You can add to /etc/profile script that will check for the users of that group and will change their Umask accordingly but as far as I know there is no `gmask` setting to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

There is no group mask for the dir and files as said by karslon. Instead, you can use the group-id

**SGID or setgid:** It inherits rights of the group of the owner of the file on execution. For directories it also may mean that when a new file is created in the directory it will inherit the group of the directory (and not of the user who created the file).

*Numerical Representation of setgid:*

```
Octal Binary   Representation
0   000     setuid, setgid, sticky bits are cleared
1   001     sticky bit is set
2   010     setgid bit is set
3   011     setgid and sticky bits are set
4   100     setuid bit is set
5   101     setuid and sticky bits are set
6   110     setuid and setgid bits are set
7   111     setuid, setgid, sticky bits are set
```