# Daemon file access denied while it shouldn't

Tags: debian, permissions, exim

I recently installed a new SSL certificate and then also decided to tighten security a bit by make the private key less readable.

This caused a problem with exim.

The certificate is now 640 with user `root` and group `ssl`. The user `Debian-exim` is in this group.

I can access the private key file just fine from the shell:

```
#sudo -u Debian-exim cat key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However, the log file of exim says otherwise:

```
2012-04-21 00:00:00 <Message-id> unable to open private key file for reading: /.../key
2012-04-21 00:00:00 <Message-id> == some@email <some@email> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-1): smtp transport process returned non-zero status 0x0100: exit code 1
2012-04-21 00:00:00 <Message-id> Frozen
```

Using *auditd* I checked the filesystem access:

```
time->Sat Apr 21 00:00:00 2012
type=PATH msg=audit(1335027881.290:6): item=0 name="/.../key" inode=1794200 dev=09:01 mode=0100640 ouid=0 ogid=105 rdev=00:00
type=CWD msg=audit(1335027881.290:6):  cwd="/var/spool/exim4"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1335027881.290:6): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=16184f8 a1=0 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=11831 pid=11847 auid=4294967295 uid=100 gid=102 euid=100 suid=100 fsuid=100 egid=102 sgid=102 fsgid=102 tty=pts1 ses=4294967295 comm="exim4" exe="/usr/sbin/exim4" key="sslkey"
```

Which shows that it indeed fails (though I don't know why). In comparison an as-identical-as-possible successfull calle (file group is changed to `Debian-exim` as opposed to `ssl`)

```
time->Sat Apr 21 00:00:00 2012
type=PATH msg=audit(1335028586.882:34): item=0 name="/.../key" inode=1794200 dev=09:01 mode=0100640 ouid=0 ogid=102 rdev=00:00
type=CWD msg=audit(1335028586.882:34):  cwd="/var/spool/exim4"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1335028586.882:34): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=11 a0=24f74f8 a1=0 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=13958 pid=13961 auid=4294967295 uid=100 gid=102 euid=100 suid=100 fsuid=100 egid=102 sgid=102 fsgid=102 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="exim4" exe="/usr/sbin/exim4" key="sslkey"
```

**I have no idea what goes wrong**. Why can the exim daemon access the "key" file when the file group is `Debian-exim` (primary group of `Debian-exim` user) but not when the file group is `ssl` (a secondary group of `Debian-exim` user)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groups that a user is in are granted by the login process. When a daemon switches to a user and group after launch, it typically only switches to this user and group (with `setgid` followed by `setuid`), and doesn't take on any other group implied by `/etc/passwd` (primary group) and `/etc/group` (supplementary group). I haven't checked that exim behaves this way, but if it doesn't, it's unusual.

You can check what groups the exim process is running as by running `grep '^Groups:' /proc/1234/status` where `1234` is the PID of an exim process.

You need to make the key file readable by either the `Debian-exim` user or the `Debian-exim` group. [Make sure ACLs are turned on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/permission-of-saved-files/12847#12847), then add `Debian-exim` to the ACL of the key file and any non-public directory leading to it:

```
setfacl -m group:Debian-exim:r /path/to/key
setfacl -m group:Debian-exim:x /path/to
```

Comment: Good explanation. I had thought of ACL but the filesystems currently doesn't have it enabled so I guess I'll start working on that.