# How to restrict to run commands in specific directory through SUDOERS?

Tags: sudo

I can configure sudo (via the sudoers file) to allow a user to run the `chown` and `chmod` commands on any file or directory in the system. However, I only want to grant a user permission to run these commands on files that reside beneath the `/var/www/html` directory.

How can I restrict privileged commands such that the user may only run them in a pre-specified directory?

For example: The following command grants 777 permissions to `index.html` file.

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/index.html
```

Now I want to perform two actions

1. Restrict `sudo` such that the user may only run `chmod` and `chown` from within `/var/www/html`
2. Disallow the user from executing these commands elsewhere in the system (e.g. the commands cannot be run in `/var/www` or `/var/ftp`)

Comment: Please don't crosspost - http://superuser.com/questions/456662/how-to-restrict-to-run-commands-in-specific-directory-through-sudo

Comment: Is this really the right way?  How about a `www-data` group eliminating the need to `chmod`/`chown` anything?

Comment: Cool. That way you get root pretty easy. It is a very bad idea to give away `chown`. Apart from that I see no reason why `chmod` has to be run as root.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're asking is difficult if not impossible. Even if you did restrict the application of `chown` and `chmod` to files under a specific directory, someone could still pass a symbolic link and so affect files anywhere they like.

Fortunately, it's highly likely that what you're attempting to do is just not the right solution to your actual problem, and there is another method that works.

Usually, users who need additional permissions to create and modify files under `/var/www` are added to a group (often `www-data`, or you may have different groups for different parts of the site). You can use group ownership and setgid directories: `chgrp www-data /var/www/html; chmod g+ws /var/www/html` allows everyone in the `www-data` group to write to the `/var/www/html` directory, and files created in that directory will be owned by the `www-data` group instead of the primary group of the user who created the file. However, this is not very flexible.

What you probably should do is set up [access control lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) for files under `/var/www`. First, make sure that ACLs are enabled: the filesystem that `/var/www` is on must be mounted with the `acl` option. See [Make all new files in a directory accessible to a group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/make-all-new-files-in-a-directory-accessible-to-a-group/12847#12847) for help on that. Also install the ACL utilities (`getfacl` and `setfacl`). Then give extra permissions to the tree under `/var/www/html` to the users who should have them. You can set per-user ACLs, but it's often easier to put users who should have the same rights on a part of the filesystem in a group and set ACLs for that group. For example, if the users in the group `html-writers` should have read-write access to the tree under `/var/www/html`:

```
setfacl -d -m group:html-writers:rwx /var/www/html
setfacl -m group:html-writers:rwx /var/www/html
```

Comment: Concerning _"this is not very flexible"_ (at the end of paragraph 3) — why is it not? Is it because people need to be in a certain group? (I know barely nothing about permissions and ACL and related things.)

Comment: @KajMagnus It's inflexible because root has to manage groups, and files can only belong to a single group. ACL let any user select who can access the files they own, and multiple users and groups can be mentioned in an ACL
.

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict the command to be used by "myuser" with all arguments in `/etc/sudoers` file with the command `visudo` add:

```
## Allows myuser to chmod the html dir and chmod 755 the html2 dir
myuser  ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/chmod [0-7][0-5][0-5] /var/www/html/*,/bin/chown myuser:mygroup /var/www/html/*,/bin/chmod 755 /var/www/html2/myapp/*.txt
```

enable logging for every operation adding:

```
Defaults logfile=/var/log/sudo.log
```

sample output:

```
[root@myhost /]# su - myuser
-sh-3.1$ sudo /bin/chmod 755 /var/www/html/index.html 
-sh-3.1$ sudo /bin/chmod 755 /var/www/html/*
-sh-3.1$ sudo /bin/chmod 777 /var/www/html2/myapp/*.txt
Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/chmod 777 /var/www/html2/myapp/*.txt' as root on myhost.mydomain.
-sh-3.1$ sudo /bin/chmod 755 /var/www/html2/myapp/*.txt 
-sh-3.1$
```

When you use sudo, the premise should be that "myuser" is a trusted person.
Be carefull with file permissions, there is no a simple way to stop a malicious sudo user from link a file from an external resource and change it.

Comment: I have tried it before, but it gave the error as:

Sorry, user prashant is not allowed to execute '/bin/chmod 777 /var/www/html/a' as root on prashant.xyz.com.

Comment: have you switched user with `su - prashant` or `su prashant`?

Comment: Yes I am executing command by prashant user.
I read forums,they say commands run system-wide.
No one has write about such issue.

Comment: I run it whooo :). But this will be static command. **Can we make it general so that I can apply any permission on any file under /var/www/html?**

Comment: 1) The sudoers file is read when the user login, if you logged in with `su prashant` the sudoers file isn't readed. 
2)Make sure that you have entered the commands with all arguments when edit with visudo to limit the action of the command in a specified dir.
3) use the wildcard as you want; if you put `/var/www/*` your limit is the /var/www dir, if you put `/var/*` the limit is all the var and so on...

Comment: `/bin/chmod [0-7][0-7][0-7] /var/www/html/*` should also work

Comment: Should probably note the limitations. It will only work with absolute paths and it won't support any extra parameters for `chmod` and `chown`.

Comment: @tombolinux It works like charm. 

Now I trying same thing with chown command. I can't get the rid of  Regular expression for username:username.

Comment: probably `[0-9a-zA-Z]+:[0-9a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: This is completely insecure: `sudo /bin/chmod 666 /var/www/html/../../../etc/passwd` And if you somehow fix that, `ln -s /etc /var/www/html/foo/etc; sudo /bin/chmod 666 /var/www/html/foo/etc/passwd`

Comment: @Gilles I agree with you. While maybe possible to filter which kind of file can be chmodded with a regex, there isn't a safe solution to stop a sudoer user to chmod 666 a link to other resource.

Comment: maybe disallow `ln -s ` for the user ?

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a fairly simple way to do this, by creating a Bash (or shell of your choice) script to restrict the modifications made to a particular file or directory.

In your example, it would look like this:

```
$ vi /usr/local/bin/mychmod

#!/bin/bash

chmod 777 /var/www/index.html
```

Then you would change the sudoers file to allow www-data to execute /usr/local/bin/mychmod.

Keep in mind however, that allowing user input (for example, allowing a user to change which file or directory is chmodded) into this space is extremely dangerous, and you need to know how to filter out injection attacks if you want to do anything like that. An attacker could easily execute any command as root this way, effectively compromising the security of your system.

Comment: this is exceptionally dangerous and really doesn't solve the solution...