# How to allow www-data to create a folder without giving read access to the parent folder

Tags: debian, permissions, sudo, apache-httpd, access-control

I'm not exactly sure the right question to ask, so I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do.

I have an internal web application (in PHP) that I want to be able to create a folder. The trouble is that the Apache user www-data doesn't have any access to the parent folder that I want my folder to be created in.

I don't think it's appropriate to give www-data access to the parent folder, so I'm wondering if I can create a script somewhere that www-data can run which has more privileges than www-data does. The script would simply do something like this (psuedocode):

```
FOLDER_NAME = sanitise(<arg-val-1>)
mkdir /some-path/$FOLDER_NAME
```

Where would it be appropriate to create this script, and how would it be run by www-data as root? (Or alternatively, is there a better way to solve the problem?)

I'm running Debian Linux.

Comment: I believe if you give just `x` permission it will allow the user to traverse the parent folder (I.e. pass through it to access its folder) but not list its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you state in a useful way, but there's undoubtedly something that's close enough and that will do what you really want.

Even if you arranged to create the directory, the `www-data` user would still not be able to access `/some-path/subdirectory`, because the subdirectory can only be accessed through the parent directory. (There are ways around this, but none that I recommend. You can have a process that can access both `/some-path` and `/some-path/subdirectory` change to `/some-path/subdirectory`, then drop privileges; the resulting process will still be able to access its current directory (but not through its absolute path). You can bind-mount the directory in another location, but if you're going to do that you might as well create the directory elsewhere.)

Arrange for these directories to be located under a directory that `www-data` can at least access (`x` permission bit). If the problem is that the directory must belong to another user and another group, set an access control list on the directory (`setfacl -m user:www-data:x /some-path`) — see [How to restrict to run commands in specific directory through SUDOERS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/how-to-restrict-to-run-commands-in-specific-directory-through-sudoers/44623#44623) for more information.

If the `www-data` user cannot write to `/some-path`, you'll still need elevated privileges to create the directory. You'll need to do at least two things, perhaps three:

1. create the subdirectory as a user with sufficient privileges;
2. if necessary, change the ownership of the subdirectory;
3. if necessary, change the permissions of the subdirectory.

If the subdirectory must belong to the `www-data` user, you can create it as a group who can write to `/some-path`. If necessary, set an ACL that allows `some-group` to write to `/some-path`: `setfacl -m group:some-group:rwx /some-path`. Then give `www-data` the right to execute the `mkdir` command with [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). Run `visudo` and add the following rule:

```
 www-data ALL = ( : some-group) /bin/mkdir /some-path/[0-9A-Z_a-z]*, !/bin/mkdir /some/path/[!-0-9A-Z_a-z]
```

This allows `www-data` to run `sudo -g some-group mkdir /some-path/foo-bar` to create subdirectories in `/some-path`.

If the subdirectory must belong to another user who can write to `some-path`, run the `mkdir` command as that user. You might be able to arrange for the directory to have the correct permissions and ownership at creation time. For the `sudoers` file:

```
www-data ALL = (some-user : some-group) /bin/mkdir -m 775 /some-path/[0-9A-Z_a-z]*, !/bin/mkdir /some/path/[!-0-9A-Z_a-z]
```

Run `sudo -u some-user -g some-group mkdir -m 775 /some-path/foo-bar` to create a group-writable directory belonging to `some-user:some-group` under `/some-path`.

Comment: This stuff makes my head spin! Thanks for your effort on this; I will come back to it next week.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the following way suite your situation or not:

Let assume following

- A www-data writable directory : */var/www/data*
- Original intended paretn directory : */home/parent*

Do this:

```
ln -s /var/www/data /home/parent/data
```

So instead of www-data writing directly under /home/parent, *data* can be access under *parent* through the soft link.

---

It can also be done with a local mount as follow

```
mount -o bind /var/www/data /home/parent/data
```

Or mount to *parent* directly

```
mount -o bind /var/www/data /home/parent
```

With local mount method, the destination directory behave as normal file system.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea, but I think one that isn't ideal in my situation, as it may create confusion with backups and other location-based scripting.

Comment: update answer with local mount method.