# Group within group file permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, files, users, group

I tried finding this on here, but couldn't so sorry if it's a duplicate.

Say I have 2 groups and a user: group1, group2, user1
with the following structure: group1 is a member of group 2, user1 is a member of group1

Now say I have the following files with relevant permissions

```
file1 root:group1 660
file2 root:group2 660
```

Now when I log into user1, I'm able to edit file1, but not edit file2. Short of adding user1 to group2, is there any way of doing this? or is there no way?

I'm using Ubuntu btw.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the classic group-based permissions in Linux do not allow you to put a group inside another group. So did you installed something which enables this feature?

Comment: A User can be a member of several groups. If you add User1 to group2 he is able to change File2. The command of your choice would be useradd.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf I didn't change anything... From what I could tell, Ubuntu allows it by default...

Comment: @user1146332 The whole point is to not add user1 to group2. If that is the only way then I can do that, but theoretically I'd prefer a group nesting structure...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no such thing as a group being a member of a group. A group, by definition, has a set of user members. I've never heard of a feature that would let you specify “subgroups” where members of subgroups are automatically granted membership into the supergroup on login. If `/etc/group` lists `group1` as a member of `group2`, it designates the user called `group1` (if such a user exists, which is possible: user names and group names live in different name spaces).

If you want user1 to have access to file2, you have several solutions:

- Make `file2` world-accessible (you probably don't want this)
- Make user1 the owner of file2: `chown user1 file2`
- Add user1 to group2: `adduser user1 group2`
- Add an ACL to `file2` that grants access to either user1 or group`:

  ```
  setfacl -m user:user1:rw file2
  setfacl -m group:group1:rw file2
  ```

  See [Make all new files in a directory accessible to a group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/make-all-new-files-in-a-directory-accessible-to-a-group/12847#12847) on enabling ACLs.

Comment: Yep, unix/linux doesn't support nested groups.  It would be usful if it did, but it just doesn't.  Windows does, and Active Directory does. LDAP does too, so it should be possible if the account and group data is in LDAP rather than in /etc/passwd and /etc/group files...but that's overkill when there are simple solutions like ACLs (or just add the user to both groups)