# setfacl: Operation not supported

Tags: rhel, nfs, acl

I have an NFS share mounted on a RHEL 6 on which I set acl option:

```
nfs_share    nfs_share_mount_point    nfs     defaults,acl        0 0
```

I need to assign an acl but I'm getting the error

```
setfacl: nfs_share_mount_point: Operation not supported
```

These are the nfs packages currently installed:

```
# rpm -qa | grep nfs
nfs-utils-lib-1.1.5-11.el6.x86_64
nfs4-acl-tools-0.3.3-7.el6.x86_64
nfs-utils-1.2.3-64.el6.x86_64
```

How could I set the acl?
thank you

Comment: is ACL enable localy ? I mean on the host that exports the filesystem ?

Comment: What NFS version is used to share and mount the filesystem?  NFS ACLs are only (officially) supported by NFSv4.

Comment: the share is mounted with version 3. The NFS packages currently installed are the ones I've reported before. Do I have to install further packages? Do I have to change something in fstab?

Comment: Linux does not support ACLs with NFSv3, even though Linux supports the old ACL concept from NFSv3 and even though this is supported  by NFSv3 on Solaris since 28 years. The problem may be that the NFSv3 standard has been established before ACLs have been introduced, but ACL support in NFS is much older than ACL support on Linux. Linux does not really support the NFSv4 ACL method either, so you seem to have no Luck with Linux and ACLs over NFS.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101096/acl-defaults-not-being-obeyed-on-copy-over-nfs