# mount options shown in /proc/mounts

Tags: filesystems, mount, linux-kernel, proc

IIRC then the mount options shown in `/proc/mounts` have changed. Some time ago `acl` and `user_xattr` were shown, now it seems that only `noacl` and `nouser_xattr` are shown if these features are turned off.

Where is this configured? Does that depend on the compiled-in defaults of the filesystem code? How can I check whether a volume supports e.g. ACL? Is there a better solution than testing with `setfacl`, `getfacl`?

Comment: Yes, checking closer, same problem using `tune2fs -l /dev/sdxN`. It shows if using `/dev/disk/by-uuid/XXX` instead of `/dev/sdxN` for some. `/dev/sdxN` for others. `root` aka `/` shows in `/proc/mounts` – but not others. Manual mounts shows in `/etc/mtab` but not `root` etc. So ... deleted answer.

Comment: @don_crissti Wow, what an extreme investigation. What makes this a comment in contrast to an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upstream decided to enable `acl` and `user_xattr` [by default](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ea6633369458992241599c9d9ebadffaeddec164) and remove them as [mount options](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/102405/) (`noacl` / `nouser_xattr` [are still](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f70486055ee351158bd6999f3965ad378b52c694) valid `mount` options hence they are shown).

Comment: Is there a way to show all flags, in whatever state they're in?

Answer (score 3):

Some filesystem types support ACLs with no mount option, others only with a mount option. For ext2/ext3/ext4, some default mount options including acl/noacl are stored in the filesystem (you can see this in `tune2fs -l /dev/BLOCK_DEVICE | grep '^Default mount options:'`). As [noted by don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79970/mount-options-shown-in-proc-mounts/79994#79994), for ext4, whether the option is shown or not depends on the kernel version (since kernel 2.6.39, `acl` defaults on no matter what the filesystem says). Filesystems such as vfat and minix have no ACL support. Filesystems such as tmpfs, xfs and zfs always support ACLs.

Unless you want to build and maintain a big table of filesystem types, versions, commands to check defaults, and kernel versions, there is no way to determine whether a filesystem supports ACLs via mount options or filesystem characteristics. You can't tell by pure observation with `getfacl` either as it will always at least report unix permissions. Even if a filesystem supports ACLs, it may not support the ACL types that you want. So your best bet is to call `setfacl` (or the underlying C APIs) to try to set the ACL you want. If the error status is EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported), you'll know that the filesystem doesn't support (this type of) ACLs.

Comment: Support of POSIX draft type ACLs in zfsonlinux (other ZFS implementations only support NFSv4 ACLs which Linux doesn't support yet (except with patches as on Suse)), is recent and AFAIK has not been officially released yet.

Comment: Is there a way to discover this information without using tune2fs? `man tune2fs` also shows that it only works with ext2,3,4 file systems? If I need to test other network mount shares like CIFS/SMB from a Windows server, what approach will do that?

Comment: Also, is there such a table of filesystem types, versions, and commands to check defaults vs kernel versions? I come across needing to have this info quite often, and quite often don't have root while investigating legacy systems.

Comment: @user658182 There's no generic way other than trying `setfacl` or the underlying `acl_xxx` functions. With a network mount, ACL only work if both the network protocol and the underlying filesystem on the server support the ACL.