# Enable ACL on ArchLinux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, acl

Hi i'm trying to enable ACL on my filesystem. this are the steps

- install acl with `# pacman -S acl`
- edit `/home` entry on `/etc/fstab`

---

```
/dev/sdb4    /home       ext4        defaults,acl,noatime        0 2
```

---

- remount partition `# mount -o remount /home`

even after reboot the acl is not displayed for the `mount` command

```
/dev/sda4 on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
```

Comment: [`acl` defaults on and isn't shown since kernel 2.6.39](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79970/mount-options-shown-in-proc-mounts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have to explicitly set `ACL` as a mount option to get it to work. None of my mounts have it explicitly set:

```
$ more /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
```

Here's my mount info:

```
$ mount
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
```

And yet I'm able to make use of `ACL` functionality on the above mounted partition.

Accessing the mounted partition:

```
$ df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root
                       50G   28G   20G  58% /
```

Am able to run `getfacl`:

```
$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
# flags: --t
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

Comment: you're absolutely right. the option dont show explicity but before I had only the root partition and did not work, move the home to another partition and now it works. is weird