# How do I know ACLs are supported on my file system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, acl

Is it enough to see `getfacl` giving no error, or do I have to check some other place to see whether or not ACLs are supported by the file systems?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're talking about a mounted filesystem, I don't know of any intrinsic way to tell whether ACL are possible. Note that “are ACL supported?” isn't a very precise question since there are several types of ACL around (Solaris/Linux/not-POSIX-after-all, NFSv4, OSX, …). Note that `getfacl` is useless as a test since it will happily report Unix permissions if that's all there is: you need to try *setting* an ACL to test.

Still on mounted filesystem, you can check for the presence of `acl` in the mount options (which you can find in `/proc/mount`). Note that this isn't enough: you also need to take the kernel version and the filesystem type in consideration. Some filesystem types always have ACL available, regardless of mount options; this is the case for tmpfs, xfs and zfs. Some filesystems have ACL unless explicitly excluded; this is the case [for ext4 since kernel 2.6.39](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79970/mount-options-shown-in-proc-mounts/79994#79994).

Comment: as for the `getfacl` test you're right. Except if I were able to find a non-default ACL (by suppressing default ones and header). Checking `/proc/mount` doesn't appear to be enough in cases where the `acl` option is a default option not coming from the mount command or `fstab`, though.

Comment: I noticed when running ZFS on Linux, with `acltype=posixacl`, the `/proc/mounts` will show `posixacl`, but in another system with just ext4, there's nothing inside `/proc/mounts`, but `acl` was a default mount option for ext4.

Answer (score 8):

acl should be enabled as default if you are using ext2/3/4 or btrfs.

Check with:

`tune2fs -l /dev/sdXY | grep "Default mount options:"`

If it isn't in the output do a:

`tune2fs -o acl /dev/sdXY`

Comment: `grep acl /etc/mke2fs.conf` will do it too.

Comment: Examining `/etc/mke2fs.conf` only tells you what the defaults would be if you created a new filesystem now.  It tells you nothing about the actual configuration used in the past when the filesystem was created (which is what `tune2fs` will do).

Answer (score 5):

To know if ACL is available you can:

1. Check current kernel version and filesystem:

   `uname -r`

   `df -T` or `mount | grep root`

   Recent distro have ACL mount option included by default (since kernel 2.6). So it's not mandatory to redefine it in /etc/fstab (or similar). Non exhaustive list of filesystems concerned: ext3, ext4, tmpfs, xfs and zfs .

   If you have older setup then you may have to recompile the kernel and/or add acl in `/etc/fstab`.
   fstab example:  `/dev/root  /  ext4  acl,errors=remount-ro 0  1`
2. Look for existing ACL settings (the "usual" config place is on /boot):

   `sudo mount | grep -i acl #optionnal`

   `cat /boot/config* | grep _ACL` 

    Depending of the system you could find the settings in `/proc`instead. Here is a way to extract the config from the .gz archive and then search for acl settings: 

   `cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip > running.config && grep -i 'acl' running.config`

   `cat running.config | grep _ACL` 

   You should see something like:

   `CONFIG_EXT3_FS_POSIX_ACL=y`

   `CONFIG_EXT2_FS_POSIX_ACL=y`

   `CONFIG_XFS_POSIX_ACL=y`

   For the filesystem you can try to get more info with:

   `sudo tune2fs -l /xxx/xxx| grep 'Default mount options:'` 

   (replace xxx/xxx by your filesystem)

--
Helpfull information can be found on:

- [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system),

- [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/51032/how-do-i-check-what-kernel-options-were-compiled-without-looking-at-boot-config/51037#comment913362_51037),

- [bencane.com](http://bencane.com/2012/05/27/acl-using-access-control-lists-on-linux/),

- [wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists)

Answer (score -1):

XFS will support it by default, and you can verify that with:

```
grep default_mntopts /etc/mke2fs.conf
```

Comment: Examining `/etc/mke2fs.conf` only tells you what the _defaults_ would be if you created a new filesystem now. It tells you nothing about the _actual_ configuration used at the time the filesystem was created.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).