# How do I mount an XFS partition enabling ACL?

Tags: mount, acl, xfs

I tried using:

```
sudo mount -t xfs -o acl /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ssd
```

I got:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1.
```

BTW, I'm using Fedora 25.

Answer (score 7):

Just use `mount` with no options. For xfs, ACL are always enabled. (That may not have been the case in the very distant past, but it would be way before Fedora 25.) This is also the case with other popular filesystems on Linux such as ext4, zfs, btrfs and tmpfs.

See also [How do I know ACLs are supported on my file system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176666/how-do-i-know-acls-are-supported-on-my-file-system) and the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists).