# How are ACL permissions processed and in what order do they apply to a given user action?

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, acl

CentOS 6.4

I'm trying to better understand how filesystem ACL rules are processed and in what order ACL rules apply.

For example, let's say users bob and joe belong to a group called sales.  Let's also say that I have a sales document with the following details:

```
[root@Maui ~]# getfacl /home/foo/docs/foo.txt
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/foo/docs/foo.txt
# owner: jane
# group: executives
user:: r--
user:bob:rw-
user:joe:rwx
group:sales:rwx
group::r--
mask::rwx
other::---
```

My question is, how are permissions processed in an example like this and what access privileges take precedence?

Is there just a top-down search and whatever rule matches first is the one that applies?

Or does Linux enforce access based on what is the most specific rule for the user in question?  Or perhaps the most restrictive and applicable rule takes precedence?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is kind of a broad topic and a little too much to cover here. I'll refer you to the [POSIX Access Control Lists on Linux](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher.pdf) whitepaper put together by Andreas Grünbacher of the SuSE Labs. It does a pretty good job of covering the subject and breaking it down so you understand how ACLs work.

#### Your example

Now let's take a look at your example and break it down.

- group (sales)
- members of sales group (bob, joe)

Now let's break down the permissions on file `/home/foo/docs/foo.txt`. ACLs also encapsulate the same permissions that most people should be familiar with on Unix, mainly the User, Group, and Other bits. So let's pull those out first.

```
user:: r--
group::r--
other::---
```

These would typically look like this in an `ls -l`:

```
$ ls -l /home/foo/docs/foo.txt
-r--r----- 1 jane executives 24041 Sep 17 15:09 /home/foo/docs/foo.txt
```

You can see who owns the file and what the group is with these ACL lines:

```
# owner: jane
# group: executives
```

So now we get into the nitty gritty of ACLs:

```
user:bob:rw-
user:joe:rwx
group:sales:rwx
```

This is showing that user `bob` has `rw`, while user `joe` has `rwx`. There is also a group which also has `rwx` similar to joe. These permissions are as if the user column in our `ls -l` output had 3 owners (jane, bob, and joe) as well as 2 groups (executives & sales). There is no distinction other than they are ACLs.

Lastly the `mask` line:

```
mask::rwx
```

In this case we're not masking anything, it's wide open. So if users bob and joe have these lines:

```
user:bob:rw-
user:joe:rwx
```

Then those are their effective permissions. If the mask were like this:

```
mask::r-x
```

Then their effective permissions would be like this:

```
user:bob:rw-    # effective:r--
user:joe:rwx    # effective:r-x
```

This is a powerful mechanism for curtailing permissions that are granted in a wholesale way.

**NOTE:** The file owner and others permissions are not affected by the effective  rights mask; all other entries are! So with respect to the mask, the ACL permissions are second class citizens when compared to the traditional Unix permissions.

#### References

- [getfacl(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getfacl)
- [POSIX Access Control Lists on Linux whitepaper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

### ACL order

First matched entry is used

- owner
- named users
- owning or named groups (groups is different, see below)
- others

[image: flow]

### Group entry

Group entry is not using the first matched, each matched group entry is checked, if any matched group entry is allow, the request is allow.

### Example

`admin` is in groups `admin` and `user`

```bash
id admin

uid=1000(admin) gid=1000(admin) groups=1000(admin),1001(user)
```

`user` is in group `user`

```bash
id user

uid=1001(user) gid=1001(user) groups=1001(user)
```

```bash
getfacl file

# file: file
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
group:user:---
group:admin:r--
mask::r--
other::---
```

```bash
getfacl first

# file: first
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
user:admin:---
group:user:---
group:admin:r--
mask::r--
other::---
```

| User | `cat file` | `cat first` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `admin` | allow | deny |
| `user` | deny | deny |

`admin` read `file` is allow

- ```bash
  getfacl file
  ...
  group:user:---
  group:admin:r--
  mask::r--
  ```
- user `admin` still allow access `file`

  (allow access if any group of the process is granted permission)

`admin` read `first` is deny

- ```bash
  getfacl first
  ...
  user:admin:---
  group:user:---
  group:admin:r--
  mask::r--
  ```
- user `admin` still deny access `first`

  (first matched named user ACL is used, even group `admin` is allow access)

> Ref: [Linux ACL](https://steelywing.github.io/note/Linux/ACL/)