# Using umask vs. setgid: best practice for peacefully sharing a directory in a Linux users group?

Tags: permissions, umask, setgid

What is the best way to share a directory between multiple Linux users?
Say I have a directory at `/foo` (a regular directory no NFS or else) and a bunch of users added to the group `bar`.

What I want is this behavior:

1. all users in `bar` can read/write files and directories in `/foo`
2. any files and directories created in `/foo` is automatically readable/writable by all users in `bar`

I am not sure what is the best way to do this:

1. I can set the group of `/foo` and its initial content to be in the `bar` group with `chown -R :bar` and set the setgid it on these with `chmod -R g+s`. I leave the umask to the default (02). There may be weird side effects to setgid on files too (the libmagic filetype get prefixed with `setgid,`  with unpredictable results for apps that use this).
2. Or I set the umask to something else for all users (say 03 or 07) but I am not sure I can get the right sharing to take place short of also using the setgid bit.

My question: what is the best, cleanest and idiomatic way to achieve this file sharing setup reliably?

PS: I wrote in the title "peacefully sharing a directory" as a tongue-in-cheek and by this I mean reliably and consistently. I think I have never been able to achieve this sharing reliably without rogue files popping up and not being accessible to the group with any setting I could try.

Comment: Pity it isn't NFS. `allsquash` + `anonuid`/`anongid` works pretty well for this.

Comment: @muru but using NFS where everything is only local would create its share of problems and possible performance issues, would it?

Comment: Yes. NFS from localhost has caused kernel panics for me, and I had to stop using it. ACLs might be simpler: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12847/70524