# How can I have a separate umask for directory or user?

Tags: users, directory, umask

I want a separate umask for a directory or a user. How can I do this?

Edit:
I am using Debian 6.

The reason why I want to do this is, I want all my SFTP users to create files with write on group. I am using a SFTP client to test to see if the umask is setting properly.

Comment: That depends… what OS are you using?

Comment: Did you look at this question?  http://serverfault.com/questions/70876/how-to-put-desired-umask-with-sftp

Comment: @Zoredache Yes.

Comment: If you ask a crap question - you get the wrong answers.

Comment: No one is complaining about getting wrong answers.

Answer (score 6):

For directories, what may work for you is using Extended ACLs and the masks, if you're on Linux.

You can have a separate umask for each user by putting the `umask xxx` command into their `~/.profile`.

Comment: Why might I be getting this error `Operation not supported`? `setfacl -d -m m:002 /srv/www/domain.com/public_html/`

Comment: I was following this guide (http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/acl.htm) and I couldn't mount the `/dev/hda6` because its not there. I am on a VPS.

Comment: `/dev/hda6` is the device node in the example on that page… odds are your server is different. You need to add the 'acl' option to the appropriate mountpoint in `/etc/fstab` and remount it (`mount -o remount,acl /dev/whatever /srv`)

Comment: I don't know what I should be adding to the fstab, so I cannot implement this properly. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need this to set default permissions for a particular system group in a folder,right? Check this [existing thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory) for the same question which covers this in detail.

Comment: I am having trouble learning how to do this. I don't know how should I be editing the fstab file.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Sorry, my solution doesn't meet your requirement. The following answer only solves the need from the user's side, not from the manager's side to force `umask` under specific dir for other users.

Provide anther solution implemented with **shell hooks** and [`direnv`](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) for **specific directory**. The following solution may be more compatible in case `setfacl` is not available on your system. (e.g. macOS)

> `direnv` is an environment switcher for the shell. It knows how to hook into bash, zsh, tcsh, fish shell and elvish to load or **unload** environment variables depending on the *current directory*.

Use `.envrc` to `export` custom `umask` value for specific dir, and the `export`ed env var will be unloaded when you leave that dir.

```bsh
# example .envrc file
export UMASK=0022
```

Define a hook to change the `umask` value once working dir is changed.

```bsh
function _umask_hook {
  if [[ -n $UMASK ]]; then
    umask "$UMASK"
  elif [[ $OSTYPE == darwin* ]]; then
    umask 0077
  else
    umask 0022
  fi
}

# To make the code more reliable on detecting the default umask
function _umask_hook {
  # Record the default umask value on the 1st run
  [[ -z $DEFAULT_UMASK ]] && export DEFAULT_UMASK="$(builtin umask)"

  if [[ -n $UMASK ]]; then
    umask "$UMASK"
  else
    umask "$DEFAULT_UMASK"
  fi
}

# zsh hooks
# trigger _umask_hook once working dir is changed
add-zsh-hook chpwd _umask_hook

# bash
# Append `;` if PROMPT_COMMAND is not empty
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND;}_umask_hook"
```

For the time being, direnv hook initialization for zsh doesn't support `chpwd` hook. If the pull request [GH-514](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/pull/514) has not been merged when you see this page. Please comment out `eval "$(direnv hook zsh)"` and hook `direnv` on `chpwd` manually with following code,

```bsh
if (( $+commands[direnv] )) && ! (( $+functions[_direnv_hook] )); then
  _direnv_hook() {
    eval "$(command "direnv" export zsh)";
  }
  typeset -agU precmd_functions;
  if [[ -z ${precmd_functions[(r)_direnv_hook]} ]]; then
    precmd_functions=( _direnv_hook ${precmd_functions[@]} )
  fi

  typeset -agU chpwd_functions;
  if [[ -z ${chpwd_functions[(r)_direnv_hook]} ]]; then
    chpwd_functions=( _direnv_hook ${chpwd_functions[@]} )
  fi
fi
```

Source: [dynamic-umask-based-on-cwd.md](https://gist.github.com/laggardkernel/38566f4473068c065f1a1ef15e6e1b4a)