# Pre-defined umask under a given path

Tags: permissions, files, zsh, umask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set default file permissions for all folders/files in a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory)

Say I have default umask, `umask1`. I would like all files/folders that I create/modify under a specific path

```
/path/to/foo
```

to have a different umask, `umask2`, and keep using `umask1` for everything else. Is there a way to have the shell do this automatically for me? If so, how?

Is there a way to do this for everyone else who belongs to the groupID of `/path/to/foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use default [ACLs](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher.pdf).

Note that the syntax is a bit different, and is based on the positive permissions, not the negative permissions mask, e.g. `rwxr-x---` would be `750` rather than `027`.

For example

```
setfacl -m d:u::7,g::5,o:0 /path/to/foo
```

or

```
setfacl -m d:u::rwx,g::r-x,o:- /path/to/foo
```

will make it so that files and directories created under `/path/to/foo` are `750` = `rwxr-x---` by default.

If you already have some subfolders, you'll want to add the `-R` flag to set their defaults recursively as well.

If you get an `Operation not supported` error, you probably don't have ACLs enabled on your file system.  The correct answer depends on many things, but if you're on Linux using ext2/ext3/ext4, try

```
sudo mount -o remount,acl <mount point>
```

or

```
sudo tune2fs -o acl <file system>
```

See also [How to set default file permissions for all folders/files in a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: When I run `setfacl -d -m g::rwx /path/to/foo` I get `Operation not supported` (?)

Answer (score 2):

You can mount the directory with specific permissions and effective umask using `bindfs`. See http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/partel/bindfs_docs/bindfs.1.html.