# Permission of any file folder set to read only on upload

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, acl

I have inherited an old CMS system that I have just cleansed from a massive hack attack. I copied all the files and databases, scrapped the old server, cleansed the files via various means, cleansed the database.. built a new ubuntu 14 server with uber safeguards (many countries blocked, trip wire and so on) and we have been running fine for a few days now.. except the original loophole that kicked all this off is still open. (a document management component)

I have to make an upgrade to this very old component which is going to take me a few days as its been heavily customised, but the weak spot it has created is that people can use a system to upload files to the images folder and execute a script

Currently I have the entire folder set to readonly which is a draconian fix to temporarily stop any new uploads.. which is preventing the component being used whereas all I need to do is set the ./images folder to read / write but just NOT execute for anything inside it.

I just to make sure than anyone uploading files using this system automatically inherit this permission (or lack of).. and ideally only allow jpg,pdf and gif file types (`.htaccess` I suspect).

How can I best set this inheritance on the images folder?

This folder is only accessed by the website (i.e `www-data:www-data`)

There is no other access of complex multiple group permissions required.

Comment: How is the script able to be executed? Does the apache user have permissions to utilize things in `/bin` `/sbin` `/usr/bin` `/usr/sbin` ,etc? I know you moved to a new server, but are you able to actually stop apache from running such things?

More importantly, to answer your question, you need to set an ACL on the folder.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory?rq=1