# what is the difference between mounting via command line and using GUI?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, directory, automounting

I am in great trouble as of now as if I have to mount my drive only using command line because if I mount my drive using GUI it gives me permission as read only for command line operations. See the image under

[image: mounted using GUI utility on ubuntu 14.04]

but if I mount the drive using command line then everything works fine. See the image under

[image: mounted using the command line utility]

What to do to resolve this issue?

I am using ubuntu 14.04. I have already tried the link under.
[How to set default file permissions for all folders/files in a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory)

but it didn't work.

Comment: welcome to U&L, please do not post screen copy, those are difficult to read and not searchable, con you edit you poste with a copy/paste of text ?

Comment: The first screenshot shows the user mayank as having read and write permissions on all files and execute permissions on all directories, so it is not clear what your problem is. On the second screenshot everyone is allowed to modify or delete everything and all files are executable, which is very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to look into the GUI interface and the options it is using to mount the filesystem.
If the option with Mount is -o to ( this implies read only) ,you may want to change it.