# I want same Permission on all directory inside it.

Tags: linux, permissions

I have directory which have 777 permission on it . I want every directory to have the same permission that i created in it or will create in it.

Comment: 777 is not a safe approach...If you still want to this, do a search in google like "how to set umask to a directory", you will certainly find what you need.

Comment: If your filesystem supports ACLs, you could set a `default acl` on directories to have special access righs set on newly created directories. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something along these lines:

```
find directory/subdirectory -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

It doesn't really make sense as to why you'd want to do it though, why would you want all the files to be executable?

Comment: The intention is to set file permissions in creation time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use umask 0777 to do this.

Comment: That's quite broad, applies everywhere, and will cause problems for e.g. `ssh` and other processes that are strict about permissions.