# Can a directory tree be given "fixed", unchangeable, permissions?

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems, shared-folders

I'd like to set up shared directory trees where users can do full read-write and execute executables, and create and delete directories, and where all new files and directories created by anyone, including root, automatically are given exactly the same permissions.  How is this done?

Comment: might be a copy of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Setting the `umask` properly ... of course, how to do that depends on exactly how you are sharing stuff - via samba (`create mask` and `directory mask` directives), sftp (umask can be set per-user or per-group in the sshd_config), etc

Comment: NFS to the LAN, Resilio sync to offline.  "g" keeps losing write.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can just create a group, and set the `/etc/sudoers` file and allow creating and deleting in a desired directory.

```
addgroup guest
usermod -a -G guest
```

in the /etc/sudoers file under group sudo

```
guest ALL:(ALL) /bin/mkdir
```

and just make the desired directory writable by giving it a reasonable chmod command.