# How can I merge the drives of two computers and see them all as one directory?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to share the drives of two computers using Manjaro Linux and see them all as one directory in both computers.

I've been using mergerfs and sshfs and it was working when I shared one drive of B with A, merged them there and shared the merged folder back with B. Now I've tried merging the drives of B too but I haven't managed to do it.

If possible I would like the computers to still work while the other is disconnected. NFS made one computer hang when the other was disconnected which is why I ended up using sshfs.

The only error I had before was some applications giving `input/output error` or `permission denied`. Which I guess it's because I didn't have the proper permissions. I would like to avoid that error too, without having to execute something like `chmod -R 777 /mnt/merged` often. I don't know if [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory) works with mergerfs.

This is what I've tried to do without success

`user@A ❯ cat /etc/fstab`

```
# <file system>                        <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=1615d12a-a9fb-41a9-a84b-34c618f16832 /mnt/hdd1    ext4          nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=d605a480-f133-443c-8fe7-5b0a2d1c60c1 /mnt/hdd2    ext4          nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
user@192.168.1.45:/mnt/hdd0  /mnt/hdd0  fuse.sshfs  IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,default_permissions,_netdev,follow_symlinks,ServerAliveInterval=45,ServerAliveCountMax=2,reconnect,noatime,auto  0  0
/mnt/hdd*  /mnt/storage  fuse.mergerfs  allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,ignorepponrename=true,func.mkdir=epall,x-gvfs-show  0  0
```

`user@B ❯ cat /etc/fstab`

```
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=301e3d8d-6c0a-4f7c-864b-4185a70efbb0 /mnt/hdd1      auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=be8b9fd3-7ed2-45ae-881a-25fa06f4de47 /mnt/hdd2      auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
user@192.168.1.122:/mnt/storage  /mnt/hdd0  fuse.sshfs  IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,default_permissions,_netdev,follow_symlinks,ServerAliveInterval=45,ServerAliveCountMax=2,reconnect,noatime 0 0
/mnt/hdd*  /mnt/storage  fuse.mergerfs  allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,ignorepponrename=true,func.mkdir=epall,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

This is what I was using. It slows the access to the merged folder since it's sharing a drive back and forth.

`user@A ❯ cat /etc/fstab`

```
# <file system>                        <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=1615d12a-a9fb-41a9-a84b-34c618f16832 /mnt/hdd1    ext4          nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=d605a480-f133-443c-8fe7-5b0a2d1c60c1 /mnt/hdd2    ext4          nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
user@192.168.1.45:/mnt/hdd1 /mnt/hdd0 fuse.sshfs _netdev,follow_symlinks,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000,ServerAliveInterval=45,ServerAliveCountMax=2,reconnect,noatime,auto,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/mnt/hdd*  /mnt/storage  fuse.mergerfs  allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,ignorepponrename=true,func.mkdir=epall,x-gvfs-show  0  0
```

`user@B ❯ cat /etc/fstab`

```
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=301e3d8d-6c0a-4f7c-864b-4185a70efbb0 /mnt/hdd1      auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=be8b9fd3-7ed2-45ae-881a-25fa06f4de47 /mnt/hdd2      auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
user@192.168.1.122:/mnt/storage /mnt/storage fuse.sshfs _netdev,follow_symlinks,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000,ServerAliveInterval=45,ServerAliveCountMax=2,reconnect,noatime,auto,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`user@A ❯ cat /etc/fstab`

```
/mnt/hdd*  /mnt/merged  fuse.mergerfs  allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,ignorepponrename=true,func.mkdir=epall,posix_acl=true  0  0

user@192.168.1.45:/mnt/merged  /mnt/shared  fuse.sshfs  _netdev,user,idmap=user,follow_symlinks,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1001,reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3,noatime,x-gvfs-show 0 0

/mnt/hdd*:/mnt/shared  /mnt/storage  fuse.mergerfs  allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,ignorepponrename=true,func.mkdir=epall,posix_acl=true,x-gvfs-show  0  0
```

`user@B ❯ cat /etc/fstab`

```
/mnt/hdd*  /mnt/merged  fuse.mergerfs  allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,ignorepponrename=true,func.mkdir=epall,posix_acl=true  0  0

user@192.168.1.122:/mnt/merged  /mnt/shared  fuse.sshfs  _netdev,user,idmap=user,follow_symlinks,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1001,reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3,noatime,x-gvfs-show 0 0

/mnt/hdd*:/mnt/shared  /mnt/storage  fuse.mergerfs  allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=partial,dropcacheonclose=true,ignorepponrename=true,func.mkdir=epall,posix_acl=true,x-gvfs-show  0  0
```

I did this in both computers

1. Change the permissions

```
❯ sudo chown $USER:$USER /mnt/storage &
❯ chmod -R ugo+rw /mnt/storage &
```

2. Set the `setgid` bit, so that files/folder under  will be created with the same group as

```
❯ chmod g+s /mnt/storage &
```

3. Set the default ACLs for the group and other

```
# Gives read,write,exec permissions for currently existing files and folders, recursively.
❯ setfacl -R -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx /mnt/storage &

# Gives rwx permissions by default, recursively.
❯ setfacl -R -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx /mnt/storage &
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the correct permissions on new files.