# Set group and mod of a new directory

Tags: linux, chmod, chown, setgid, sticky-bit

I try to set for NEW created files/directories in /home/test:

1. group to "test"
2. right to "770"

This works for the group (1).

```
chown :test /home/test
chmod g+s /home/test
```

But I do not get it for the rights (2).

I want to set this behaviour to the directory /home/test and not to a user-setting (umask).

Comment: `g+s` is for setting group ID, and thus called "set GID"  or " SGID" (bit). Sticky bit would be `t`. Apart from that: How is permissions `770` related to you setting `g+s`? `770` translates to `ug=rwx`. Also: If you know the desired octal permission, why not use it with `chmod`?

Comment: I want to have new created directories with specific group and specific rights - automatically after creation.

Comment: Ah, I now understand your question. You may set default ACL-entries for this. [See here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory)